# how to make the content of wcm 7 searchable

Tags: search, websphere, wcm

I am basically trying to make the content of WCM 7 *searchable* .That is the search will be done on data of WCM 7.

But I am stuck on it how can i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link:

http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/7.0.0/doc/en_us/pt700abd004/html-wrapper-wcm.html#wcm_dev_search

Answer (score 0):

One of my project used Omnifind to search content inside WCM, which is more powerful than builtin searching capability.